# How To Apply Animation Script To Square Box DIV In HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

**Background**

The below code creates a square box `<div class="box">` and adds an animation of different sized circles.

At the moment, the script creates an animation across the whole page, but I’m trying to apply the animation script specifically to the square box `<div class="box">`.

I’ve tried changing the script `document.body.append(circle)` to `document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].appendChild(circle)` with no success, the animation continues to apply across the whole page.

---

**Question**

What code changes are needed to apply the Script animation specifically to `<div class="box">` ?

---

**Code**

```
<html>
   <h1>Heading 1</h1>
   <div class="box">
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <p>This is some text inside a div element.</p>
   </div>
   <p>This is some text outside the div element.</p>
</html>


<style>
   .circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 100%;
   }
   .box {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   border: 5px outset red;
   text-align: center;
   }
</style>


<script>
   const colors = ["#000000"];
   const numCircles = 50;
   const circles = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < numCircles; i++) {
     let circle = document.createElement("div");
     circle.classList.add("circle");
     circle.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
     circle.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vw`;
     circle.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vh`;
     circle.style.transform = `scale(${Math.random()})`;
     circle.style.width = `${Math.random()}em`;
     circle.style.height = circle.style.width;

     circles.push(circle);
     document.body.append(circle);
   }

   circles.forEach((el, i, ra) => {
     let to = {
       x: Math.random() * (i % 10 === 0 ? -10 : 10),
       y: Math.random() * 10
     };

     let anim = el.animate(
       [
         { transform: "translate(0, 0)" },
         { transform: `translate(${to.x}rem, ${to.y}rem)` }
       ],
       {
         duration: (Math.random() + 1) * 2000,
         direction: "alternate",
         fill: "both",
         iterations: Infinity,
         easing: "ease-in-out"
       }
     );
   });  
</script>
```

---

**Image**

[image: HTML code creates a square box and the Script creates an animation of different sized circles]

Comment: You can append them to the box with `document.querySelector('.box').append(circle)` But this will not fix your problem, the problem is not with where you place them in the DOM, but the 'left' and 'top' style values you are given are related to the window size and not the size and position of the box.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
 circle.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vw`;
 circle.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vh`;
```

`vw` and `vh` use the full page width and full page height.

Change them to `%` AND replace `document.body.append(circle);` with `document.querySelector('.box').append(circle)`. Also make sure the `.box` has `position:relative` to make sure the absolute positioning stays inside the box.

---

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Two great answers here today. Appreciate it. This code applies the animation to the specified area without cropping it, which is something I did not consider, but visually looks interesting. Thanks very much. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

step1: changing the script `document.body.append(circle)` to `document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].appendChild(circle)`

step2: add below css to .box;

```css
{
  transform: scale(1);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Two great answers here today. Appreciate it. This code applies the animation to the specified area, and crops it. Thanks very much. Have a good day.